# Редакторы для программиста

Tags: html, javascript, php, ide

Привет всем. )

Подскажите бесплатные программки для верстания html, php, javascript. Желательно те, которые обновлялись хотя бы за последние два года (выходили новые версии).

Comment: > А есть шанс научить лобстера как-то
> более явно подсвечивать скобки?

Там есть Preferences->Editor->Colors->Editor->PairHighligting
где можно выставить все, что угодно.

Answer (score 9):

Vim наше все. Попробуйте, не поленитесь - и в будущем скажете "спасибо"

Comment: Только вот время на его освоение требуется. Рекомендуется прочитать Seven habits of effective text editing http://www.moolenaar.net/habits.html

Comment: Ну и, конечно же, замечательные скринкасты от Derek Wyatt: http://www.derekwyatt.org/vim/vim-tutorial-videos/

Comment: mcedit с подсветками тоже супер, удобнее Vim-а. ИМХО.

Comment: Если надо играть, а не работать, то mcedit вероятно покруче будет. (mcedit -- Minecraft World Editor)

Answer (score 6):

notepad++

Comment: няшный редактор, жаль что под линукс без вина не идет :(

Comment: Отличный блокнот с подсветкой синтаксиа, и многими функциями.
Темболее программист писал его прежде всего для себя, соответствено человек знает что нужно при работе с кодом.

Comment: Неужели вы действительно в notepade++ кодите ??
Проект наверное из пяти файликов, вот и не нужна нормальная среда разработки )..
И какие же "многими функциями" обладает notepad++ кроме подсветки синтаксиса ?

Comment: я ответил на вопрос "Подскажите бесплатные программки для верстания html, php...".
Если бы вопрос стоял: "Подскажите среду разработки которую вы используете в своих проектах", я бы воздержался от такого ответа.

Comment: Установите и посмотрите<br>
От чего же 5 файликов? у нас все в index.php, Main.java и т.д. xD<br>
Для этого открываем плагин менеджер и смотрим...

Answer (score 5):

Рекомендую Netbeans. В нём есть всё что нужно и даже больше :) 
http://netbeans.org

Comment: Поддерживаю, Netbeans + ZenCoder - вещь!

Comment: для php программиста ИМХО netbeans редкое Г...

Comment: Ух ... Они таки доделали 7 ветку :). Там кажется был встроен плагин для работы с базами данных. Интересно и как? И еще интересует, они с фтп уже наладили дружбу или все по старому? Выгружать проект полностью?

Comment: Да убожество редкое, развичто для работы с фреймворками типа Symphony удобно т.к. там плагин можно поставить...(точно ли Symphony неуверен) если вам так важна "умная" и тяжелая IDE уж лучше eclipse...<br>
Кстати на java пишу под ней, нравится, на php - ниразу...

Comment: интересно, чем же эклипс лучше?

Comment: Работает быстрее, чем Netbeans, и не лезет за обновлениями каждый раз.

Comment: Эклипс убожество редкое, и в сравнение с нетбинсом точно не идет, ИМХО. Нотепад и т.д. тем более для разработки не идет

Comment: Самый важный фактор это именно скорость, меня не прикалывает сидеть и тупить порой по минуте и ждать пока это чудо одумается, eclipse нереален в своих возможностях и при этом ИМХО работать в нем намного приятнее чем в netbeans (говорю именно о PHP..)

Comment: А я бы сказал что оба хороши. Ибо нет под линуксы лутше варианта просто напросто.

Comment: @Barton, Вы с Эклипсом вообще работали? Да от и отличается от НетБенца только более быстрой загрузкой, не шарит в поисках обновлений да отсутствует справка при выборе вложенных функций (сужу по Джава). А Notepad++ для простого написания кода -- в самый раз. Правда, только для знающих людей...

Comment: @AlexWindHope, вы на нетбуке чтоли работаете? Дома у меня приличная машина (i5 + 12Гб памяти) - глюков нет, очевидно. Но и в офисе не такие уж и мощные машины у нас. core 2 + 2Гб памяти. И глюков никаких не наблюдалось по сегодняшний день. И вообще netbeans очень удобен не только для симфони или зенда. для php может быть шторм удобней для кого-то будет. мне он не понравился.

Answer (score 3):

Да, Notepad++ - отличное решение. Очень поможет множества проблем дополнения Firefox: Firebug, WebDeveloper

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) удобная штука. Перешел на NetBeans c [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt). NetBeans работает стабильнее и быстрее..

Не используйте для программирования редакторы типа notepad, или notepad c подсветкой кода.. Они годятся только для небольших модификаций в скрипте..

Ведите разработку в средах разработки таких как [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) и [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt).

Comment: Они толстые, и у меня на рабочем нетбуке тупят

Answer (score 2):

Я прошу прощения что рекомендую платный, но цена более чем доступная. Я сам не особо люблю огромные комбайны для кодинга, потому что честно говоря мне все это не особо нравится. Люблю простоту и удобность, и это есть phpDesigner

Comment: Удобная программулина, но всё же для php. Еще на торрентах можно найти MS Expression Web 4 хотя удобнее до сих пор считаю Front Page 2003

Comment: phpDesigner очень удобен для верстки. Понимает яваскрипты и даже завернутые делишки от jquery понимает правильно. Если вы о средствах визуального редактирования штмл, то ну ... Я этого не понимаю.

Comment: Поддерживаю. Единственное, не нравятся только 2 вещи, при нестабильном инете может глючить редактирование файлов на сервере и второе, иногда выдавал ошибку связанную с utf8 при сохранении файла. Конечно это может быть глюком только моего компа.

Сейчас сижу в NuSphere PhpEd

Comment: I ♥ phpDesigner ;)

Answer (score 2):

windows = notepad++

linux = juffed, geany, gPHPedit

---

upd

Пересел на kate

---

upd2

komodo edit, gedit, notepad++

Comment: NetBeans отлично становится и на никс и на винд. На никсы даже проще, всего одной командой) PhpStorm так же идет на обеих системах

Comment: А я что писал что они не ставятся или что? я написал те редакторы которые использую сам, о netbeans и phpStorm я какбы вкурсе -.-

Answer (score 2):

**GNU Emacs**. Проверенная годами классика. Умеет все, включая всякие новоможные тренды (скажем, проверка синтаксиса CoffeeScript прямо во время написания? [да легко](https://github.com/defunkt/coffee-mode)), но для этого нужно уметь настраивать оный.

Хотя он, спасибо всяким MULE и прочим TRAMP, несколько монструозен, что время от времени подталкивает меня согрешить и попробовать пользоваться vim.

Comment: Emacs is a nice operating system, but lacks a good editor (автора не помню и лень искать)

Answer (score 2):

Если честно, то программист должен поработать в разных редакторах и выбрать для себя удобную среду "обитания"))

Comment: Кому должен и когда он успел столько задолжать? Редакторов много, а программист (для себя) -- единственный. Все не перепробуешь, если тестирование редакторов не является основным родом занятий. На освоение чего-либо приличного требуется немало времени. Тут речь уже о рефлексах идёт.

Answer (score 1):

Очень советую PhpStorm или NetBeans. Удобные средства отладки, гибкие настройки систем, SVN и т.д. Лично я больше первую юзаю.

Answer (score 1):

Пользуюсь [SciTE Ru](http://code.google.com/p/scite-ru/) и вам советую,полностью настраиваемый  редактор.Настроить можно все начиная от тега - заканчивая подсветкой.

А если платные,тогда phpDesigner или phpStorm.

Answer (score 1):

**Aptana Studio** удобный.

Еще попробуй **CodeLobster**.

Comment: А есть шанс научить лобстера как-то более явно подсвечивать скобки?

Answer (score 1):

Мне нравится PSPad.

Answer (score 1):

Под Windows использую [EmEditor](http://ru.emeditor.com/).

[image: Скрин редактора]

Достоинства:

- Очень быстрый
- Умеет открывать огромные файлы (я открывал, редактировал и сохранял файл 20Гб)
- Плагины
- Макросы на JavaScript (с возможностью записи действий пользователя)
- Вертикальные направляющие для отступов в коде (редко где видел, а здесь есть)
- Возможность кастомного запуска внешних приложений (Запросто можно прикрутить си-компилятор. STDOUT компилятора возвращается в отдельный блок вывода, в котором, в свою очередь, настраивается парсер ошибок. В результате переход на строку с ошибкой в коде по клику.)
- Удобный поиск (с индивидуальной подсветкой результатов)
- Каждый файл открывается в отдельном процессе (удобно если один из процессов обрабатывает очень большой файл)
- Сравнение файлов
- Пользовательская настройка подсветки кода (в том числе и на основе регулярок)

Все вышеперечисленное - не копипаст с оффсайта, а мнение основанное на опыте использования. Начинал работать с ним еще с версий 8-ми летней давности.

Недостаток один, он платный. Стоит примерно 40$, но оправдывает свою цену на все 100%.

Comment: А почему не в число недостатков не включено ограничение виндами? И ещё вопрос, 20Гб -- это были исходники? И подсветка/баланс скобок не тормозила? Однако...

Comment: 20Гб был дамп базы MySQL. Подсветка не тормозила, но, правда, и скобочные блоки там не очень большие. На счет ОС я написал в начале.

Comment: Да я видел, что написано, просто зачастую это не считают недостатком.

Comment: *И правильно делают* ^,,,^

Answer (score 1):

С недавних под отказался от PyCharm & PHPStorm в пользу Sublime Text 2. Может быть и Вам понравится.

Answer (score 0):

Многофункциональный, и очень удобный **Dreamweaver** от Macromedia или Adobe

Comment: Чем если не секрет?

ИМХО - редко Г как первое так и второе

Answer (score 0):

Используйте Notepad++, удобный и легкий в управлении.