# Редакторы HTML

Tags: html, css, ide

Подскажите хорошие редакторы для создания сайтов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/38144/редакторы-для-программиста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/38144/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0)

Answer (score 0):

http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ +плагины.

Answer (score 0):

amaya. W3C's editor/browser for the web